# Android-fragment,viewpager,activity relation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

- I have one activity(MainActivity) and corresponding xml file. Xml file contains the toolbar on the top, then the sliding tabs then then viewpager.
- I have 3 fragments(corresponding xml files) and 3 SlidingTabs. Tab 1 is connected with fragment 1 and 2 with 2 and 3 with 3.
- If I am performing any operations on the views in the fragments, Do I need to write all the code in MainActivity or in the Fragment?
- Do I have to return only the view from the fragment for that pager or all the  codes for that page should also be there inside fragment?

**For Ex:**

If I am retrieving some data using contentresolver and populating the data on the listview in 1st fragment, Likewise, If I am doing some other operations and displaying the details in fragment 2 and 3, Do I need to write all the codes in the corresponding fragment itself or I have to write in MainActivity.

Can someone provide the answer to this or any link which will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Tabs with View pager, then MainActivity will just act as container and it holds Fragments. 
So you can write respective code on respective fragments only. Any thing needed as common for all fragments then you can write in MainActivit. For Example Tool bar title changes, Option menu's ect..

Comment: Thanks! If I use single Activity for all the fragments then how can I get the context in fragments. Which one I have to use? getActivity() or getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: you can use getActivity() for context. Also you can initialize your activity instance like MainActivity mainActivty = (MainActivity) context;

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to return only the view from the fragment for that pager.And all the codes for that page should be inside fragment itself.

Only common codes or if you want to define any call back methods from the fragment, their implementations can we done in your activity.

Refer the below link where you can get an idea of your tabs implementation with few common material design controls.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Thanks! So, If I use 3 fragments, Only common code I have to write inside MainActivity. I will have to write all the codes inside fragments itself. The MainActivity will be control all 3 fragment right? And Do I need to have an empty contructor inside all fragment?

Comment: Ya only if any common code if required. And no need of empty constructor if you use parameterised contructor while initialising your fragment.

Comment: I have an adapter class which will bind the fragments to the pages and I didn't use any constructor in the fragment but I am initializing them in the adapter as Tab1 tab1=new Tab1(), how to use parametarized constructor?